# Doesn Intellij IDEA have a 'beans' view like Spring IDE in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

When working on Java/Spring projects in Eclipse, there is a handy 'beans' view one can use to declare beans and their properties in XML configuration files as the picture herein illustrates. Does Intellij IDEA have any such option even if via some plugin?

[image]

Comment: There is a Spring window, which provides similar functionalities. However, this is only available with the Spring integration, which is only available in the Ultimate version.

Comment: You should enable Spring facet (**File > Project structure > Facets**) on your project in Idea, then you'll see the **Spring** tab in the bottom of the IDE window.

Comment: In addition @dunni 's comment, you can check out all the spring related features [on their site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/spring.html).

Comment: @dunni While I did see the Spring window you are talking about, I did not see the kind of functionality I was asking about in the question. I guess IDEA doesn't have it then?

Comment: the spring editor window is only available in the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version.
Press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`A` to open the action window and type `spring`. It should be there if you have the right version and the Spring plugins installed.